# Angular6 @ViewChild undefined with ngIf

Tags: angular, viewchild

I've a problem using @ViewChild with a component showed through ngIf. I found various solutions but no one usefull for me.
This is my main component, consisting of various step (I showed only 2 in code for brevity) with a button for forward navigation and a button to reset the component returning on first step. First step is showed on page opening:

```html
...
<div class="my-container">
    <first-child *ngIf="showFirtChild"></first-child>
    <second-child *ngIf="showSecondChild"></second-child>
</div>
<button (click)="goToNextStep()"></button>
<button (click)="reset()"></button>
...
```

```js
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild(FirstChild) private firstChildComp: MyFirstChildComponent;
    showFirtChild: boolean = true;

    ngOnInit() {
        //here firstChildComp is defined
    }

    //code for navigate through steps
    reset() {
        this.showFirtChild= true;
        this.firstChildComp.fillTable(); //fillTable is a function defined in MyFirstChildComponent
    }
...
}
```

During steps navigation the reference to firstChildComp is lost and when reset() is called, childComp results undefined. I know the cause is ngIf, so I tryed to use ngAfterViewInit:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.fcomp = this.firstChildComp;
}

reset() {
        this.showFirtChild= true;
        this.fcomp .fillTable();
}
```

but it doesn't resolve my problem.
Any suggestion?

Comment: In the `ngAfterViewInit` stage, you can get the subcomponents. Is the `fillTable` method private?

Comment: No method is public

Answer (score 28):

As Angular's Doc says:

> "True to resolve query results before change detection runs. If any query results are inside a nested view (such as *ngIf), the
>   query is resolved after change detection runs."

So, passing the param `{ static: false }` to @ViewChild resolve the problem, as it is accessed on ngAfterViewInit, instead on `{ static: true }` is accessed before change detection runs so on ngOnInit.

Comment: static option is only available from version 8+ (according to Angular docs)

Answer (score 20):

ngIf will remove you component from the DOM. So it becomes undefined.
If you use `[hidden]="!showFirstChild"` instead, it will be only hidden, and will be available in the component.

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rw1ukg) where you can check this.

Comment: Using hidden works correctly but I prefer to user ngIf because I pass data through various step.

Comment: Humm, then I guess dince12 solution is ideal.

Answer (score 16):

Try running change detection in between to ensure the DOM template is reading the DOM after the change in reset.

In template:

```html
<first-child #firstChild *ngIf="showFirtChild"></first-child>
```

In controller:

```js
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

export class exampleClass implements 
{

  @ViewChild('firstChild') public firstChildComp: MyFirstChildComponent;
  public fcomp: any;
  public showFirtChild: boolean;

  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef,
            //your services) {}

  public ngAfterViewInit() 
  {
      this.showFirtChild = true;
      this.ref.detectChanges();

      this.fcomp = this.firstChildComp;
  }

  public reset(): void 
  {
      this.fcomp.fillTable();
  }
}
```

[ChangeDetectorRef Documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) for further reading.

Comment: sorry check edit, should be good. If that does not work please explain whats not happening or any errors.

Comment: With your edit fcomp in reset() is correctly defined but nothing changes. This is very strange, it's like the fillTable() is executed, infact no errors appear, but it does nothing... Using debugger I can see that fcomp is correct and  the instruction is executed but the table is not filled...

Comment: Okay so you have sorted the viewChild problems? Not sure I can help with populating the table correctly. Put a console.log(); in fillTable(); and if you can see it then there is a problem with the function.

Comment: It's not problem of the table, because each other method of MyFirstChildComponent is executed but it actually does nothing.

Comment: So if in MyFirstChildComponent you ran this.fillTable() it would work ?

Comment: Sorry, I try to explain: on page opening I call reset() and it works correctly. After passing to other step and back to first recalling reset() it doesn't work. I repeat it's like the method is executed but nothing changes (this happens for each other method of child component). I note this: on second reset(), ngAfterViewInit() isn't executed, so I thing fcomp is defined but, in fact, it doesn't work properly.

Comment: So has this fixed the issue with the viewchild being undefined?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunatly doesn't solve my problem totally. Thanks

Comment: this is the only thing that worked why isn't this answer accepted and +322342?

Comment: haha I think the poster was having a unrelated problem as well, glad to help :-)

Comment: This helped me a lot and is very simple to do. I don't understand though why Angular doesn't run change detection after the ngif is toggled...

Comment: Works perfectly on Angular < 8 version, thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for an answer, you can also try setting the static flag value on true. That will make the child component `viewContainerRef` loads depending on the `ngIf` value.