# What is the equivalent of control.disable in case of QueryList in angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms, disabled-input

I need to disable some fields based on my angular form. I am trying to disable the DOM elements in component class because many html tags are customized and so disabled attribute cannot be used there. The way I am doing this is using @ViewChild/@ViewChildren in my component and disabling in ngAfterViewInit(). I am not able to disable the elements which are inside ngIf in html. Below is the code:
Html:

```
<div *ngIf="displayAdvOpt">
        <div class="card-title">Rules</div>
        <abc-select-field
          #rule
          width="100%"
          label=" "
          formControlName="_rules"
          [options]="rules"
        ></abc-select-field>
<div>
```

Component class:

```
@ViewChildren('rule') ruleSelect;
```

When logging ruleSelect in component class, it shows that is a QueryList and not a FormControl, as is the case for the elements not inside ngIf. Due to this, I am not able to do ruleSelect.control.disable() to make it disabled in html. I am doing these in ngAfterViewInit().
Please let me know how can I disable a QueryLst or if there is any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Abhinash, you can not acces to any element if is not in the screen. As you has the element under a *ngIf you need condition becomes true and "after Angular repaint", enable/disable... so, in general

```
this.condition=true;
setTimeout(()=>{
   this.ruleSelect.....
})
```

But your abc-select-field, has a FormControl in any way and the FormControl exist even the abc-select-field is not in screen, so if you makes that the elements are disabled depending if the control is disabled

Answer (score 0):

In order to disable the select field, you don't need to know neither that 'distinction' (QueryList/Control) nor a 'local reference' (#rule) :

Simply, in the code you want to disable, you just need to do this:

```
this.form.get('_rules').disable();
// or this.form.constrols['_rules'].disable();
```

Similarly, when you want to re-enable it you can use:

```
this.form.get('_rules').enable();
```

Comment: I already tried this option but it was not working. Sorry to not mention in the question.

Comment: "<abc-select-field" is a component of yours?

Comment: yes, its a customized component provided by the client.

Comment: Can you bind it a property [disabled], and bind to it a boolean (example, <abc-select-flied [disabled]="yourVariableBoolean...)", and change the code inside the customized component to disable/enable according to this variable? Or is not an option to edit the component?

Comment: is complicated to edit the component and release for us to use. thats why, I had to take the option for ViewChild. Also, if <abc-select-flied> is not inside an ngIf, then I am able to disable it using @ViewChild.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the workaround I tried.

```
<div *ngIf="displayAdvOpt">
            <div class="card-title">Rules</div>
            <abc-select-field
              #rule
              width="100%"
              label=" "
              formControlName="_rules"
              [options]="rules"
              on-mouseover="isDisabled()"
            ></abc-select-field>
    <div>
```

In component class:

```
@ViewChild('rule') ruleSelect;
isDisabled() {
    if (this.showChanges){
      this.ruleSelect.control.disable();
    }
```

I see that in ngAfterViewInit(), ruleSelect is a QueryList but in isDisabled() the method called after on-mousehover, it is coming as AbcSelectFieldComponent and so I can call .control.disable() on it. The only reason I can think of is this- https://stackoverflow.com/a/55610325/4464806
Anymore suggestions are welcome!!